# remove <div class="textwidget"> from text-widget

Tags: functions, widgets, text

When you add a text widget to a sidebar in Wordpress the widget includes this code

```
<div class="textwidget">
```

How do I remove this without editing the core?

FYI - I think this line is located here:
wp-includes/default-widgets.php (line 383)

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The widgets can have specific ID's.

Comment: I use a jquery box with some cool effects together with that text app, so the div messes up the css a bit. If there was an easy way to remove it it would save me alot of time :)

Comment: Well the easiest way to remove it would be to use jquery's `.remove`.

Comment: And could you explain how? :)

Comment: Better using jQuery to remove a div after the fact that re-making a clean widget with the exact functionality you need?

Comment: does the jquery box thing not add additional css classes or markup you can then use to write CSS selectors that cancel out the text-widget styling?

Comment: Aside from using JavaScript or creating your own custom text widget, there's no current way to remove the textwidget div.

Answer (score 9):

OK, attempting to remove the  with jQuery is counter intuitive.

Modifying it via output buffering is inefficient.

And we shouldn't edit the actual widget code itself, since this will revert back next time we update WordPress.

I would suggest either creating your own text widget, or simply extend and modify the existing WordPress widget as follows (put the following code in your functions.php file):

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_my_widgets' );


function register_my_widgets() {
    ...
    register_widget( 'My_Text_Widget' );
}

class My_Text_Widget extends WP_Widget_Text {
    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract($args);
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['title'] ) ? '' : $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $text = apply_filters( 'widget_text', empty( $instance['text'] ) ? '' : $instance['text'], $instance );
        echo $before_widget;
        if ( !empty( $title ) ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; } ?>
            <?php echo !empty( $instance['filter'] ) ? wpautop( $text ) : $text; ?>
        <?php
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to remove the actual div with the textwidget class applied to it but not it's content, this is a simple method using jQuery:

```
$('.textwidget').replaceWith($('.textwidget').contents());
```

Comment: This is absolutely nothing one should do in the frontend…

Comment: @feela could you please elaborate on your comment and better explain what is the issue with the answer?

Answer (score -1):

As per the comment, in the case it is probably better to just remove or replace the class name using jQuery then a php function, since that class is hardcoded anyhow.

To remove it.

```
jQuery('.textwidget').remove();
```

To set the css to hide it.

```
jQuery('.textwidget').css('display', 'none');
```

To change the class name

```
jQuery('.textwidget').attr('class', 'newName');
```

Comment: This will probably remove the class right? But the problem here is the div

Answer (score -3):

You can use output buffering (http://php.net/manual/es/book.outcontrol.php) to get the whole generated page in a variable and remove the offending  before echoing.

But it seems overly complicated for this case. You can just copy all the widget code and create a new widget (in a plugin or your functions.php) without that hardcoded div. It's really not that much code.

Also, any reason to remove that div that can not be solved in css?

Comment: Why the downvotes? any better solution?

Answer (score -3):

1. Edit file: /wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-text.php
2. Find, Delete: `<div class="textwidget">` and `</div>`
3. Done!

Comment: 4. Watch your changes being overwritten after the very next WordPress update. 5. Understand why you should not change core files.

Comment: You should never modify WordPress core files if you can avoid it.